# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
    void verileriBas(string startIP, string endIP, string locID)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=W7\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=GeoLocation1;Integrated Security=true;");
        con.Open();
       //ask if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open(); 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into dbo.Blocks (startIP,endIP,locID )values(@startIP,@endIP,@locID)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startIP", startIP);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endIP", endIP);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locID", locID);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();


    }
```

Comment: AddWithValue creates parameters of the datatype of the value. If you pass strings every parameter is a string. Then what is the datatype of your database fields?

Comment: What are the types of your columns? Sounds like they are numerical but..

Comment: And what is the content of your two IP variables? startIP and endIP

Comment: You are passing the string parameters in your function. Try `void verileriBas(int startIP, int endIP, int locID)` in your function.

Comment: Please don't repost questions. Edit your original one instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176304/sqlexception-was-unhandled-turkey

Answer (score 1):

> All data type int

Your question is totally unclear but I think you try to say with sentence; all your columns are `int` in your database.

But let's take a look at your method definition;

```
void verileriBas(string startIP, string endIP, string locID)
```

Your values are `string`. You try to insert them in an `int` typed columns. And your sql server says:

> *Hey, you try to insert character values in a numeric column.*

which clearly is not allowed. Numeric column types are for numeric values, character column types are for character values. Use proper column types for your proper type of values.

You have 2 options;

- Parse your string to integer if they are *really* numeric values or
- Change your database column types to character type to keep your values as a string